# Customize selector colors for mvxbindablelist using mvvmcross / mono droid

Tags: android-listview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I wanted to customize the highlight color of the mvxbindable listview from the standard orange to a color set dynamicly. I thought this to be easy however I was wrong :)

I found that I should set the background drawable of the list item in the adapter using a StateListDrawable. I do this in the following way(the green color is for test and _backgroundGradient is created in the constructor);

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view =base.GetView(position, convertView, parent);

            StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();


            sld.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateFocused }, new ColorDrawable(Color.Green));

            sld.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, new ColorDrawable(Color.Green));

            sld.AddState(new int[] {}, _backgroundGradient);

            view.Focusable = true;

            if (view != null)
            {
                view.SetBackgroundDrawable(sld);     
            }


            return view;
        }
```

However when the list item is clicked no color i shown. The following is from my xml:

```
<listitem>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/dk.appsfabrikken.cmsapp"
  android:id="@+id/tableViewItem"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="90dp"
  android:paddingBottom="1dp"

  local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'ShowCellDetails'}}">

  <CmsApp.Droid.Controls.UmbracoImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewImagePreview"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:padding="5dp"
    local:MvxBind="{'ImageData':{'Path':'ImageIconData'},'HideImage':{'Path':'Hidden'}}" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/table_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Title'}}" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I must be missing something - any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved it myself. It might be a rookie mistake but hey I solved it. I tried adding a click event to the view as well and this was not triggered either. So I decided to add the StateListDrawable to the linearlayout of the listitem instead of the background of the view. This solved my issue.

I added the following to my method in the adapter:

```
  var ll = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.tableViewItem);
            if (ll != null)
            {
                ll.SetBackgroundDrawable(sld);
            }
```

I am still not entirely sure why it did not work when I added it to the view background.
I hope this might save someone else's day as it ruined mine :)

Comment: You know you can do that directly in the XML?

Comment: Yes, but the definition of the colors is dynamic and retrived from a webservice.